# No Shipping Method on Frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, shipping-methods

there is no shipping method available on frontend whether its flat rate or custom shipping method.

Even though the module is enabled, I can see the shipping methods if I try to create order from the admin panel, but then if i try to create from frontend with guest or as a customer there is no shipping method.

I am using Magento 2.4.2, Claue theme.

And shipping module is enabled. Can anyone please put me in the right direction to debug such error?

P.S I cannot share the domain publicly.

**UPDATE:**
If i try to create new order front admin then shipping methods are available, but if I create an order from frontend and then edit the order from admin, then shipping address etc is disabled and I cannot see shipping methods too.

[image: Shipping Method Disabled]

[image: Shippinng Address Disabled]

Answer (score 1):

Is your product virtual. For virtual product shipping method is not essential.